# mysql_real_escape_string() for $_SESSION?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function in my MySQL queries for `$_SESSION` variables? This is my code at this moment.
Hope that someone can help me.

Thanks :-)

```
<input value='<?php echo $_SESSION['reg']['data']['password1']; ?>'
```

Comment: **Stop** using `mysql_*` API. It is deprecated. Use `mysqli_*`or PDO.

Comment: @Jens I like MySQL so im gonna use it. That is not a answer for my question, however thanks anyway for the weird answer lol.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: @Yonas Nobody ever said 'stop using MySQL'.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php , http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/2864740

Comment: @CharlotteDunois If its not hard, why you don't gonna come help me on teamviewer? I have many many classes on my website its not just basic switch over to mysqli. ;)

Comment: well depends on your requirement, if session value comes from database than no need to escape it, if u are saving it from user input than u must need o prevent it.

Comment: @devpro What an .. odd statement. Always use placeholders. If you don't have placeholders, always escape. (Where 'always' means, until there is a *justified* reason to do otherwise.) Coming from the database is still subject to second-order injection. There is no reason to make 'exceptions'.

Comment: @user2864740: can u explain what dump... :p

Comment: @devpro Yea, its coming from the user input.  Can you fix it on my code? I have searched tried everything, but can't escape this.

Comment: When passwords get stored in sessions and echoed out to inputs, all kinds of alarm-bells start ringing...

Comment: No one can fix my code? @user2864740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), something like:

```
<?php

$user     = $_SESSION['reg']['data']['user'];
$password = $_SESSION['reg']['data']['password'];

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

Comment: Thanks man! 
I changed it a litle bit and now it works perfect. No SQL injection possible anymore. =)